# How to reduce Neo4j Storage Size?

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j version 3.0.3. I am  Having  126815 user Nodes and 6016519 Realtions for those Nodes.Every thing is fine but Neo4j is taken for storing this data nearly 51.18 GiB. How can we reduce this data storage.

Comment: what is the size of your transaction logs ?

Comment: How are you calculating the size? By looking at the data folder or from the neo4j browser?

Comment: yes in neo4j browser it showing 51.18 GiB.

Comment: Configure the tx-log policy in neo4j.conf to only keep 1G or 2 days of data, then most of your store should be cleaned out.

Answer (score 1):

Try store-utils: https://github.com/jexp/store-utils

Just clone the repo, use the branch which fits your database version, build and run it.

Comment: Yes, it get's rid of unused records etc and you can chose to remove labels, rel-types and properties you no longer need.